# Как можно сгенерировать список всех комбинаций цифр четырехзначного числа?

Tags: python, математика

Как можно сгенерировать список всех комбинаций цифр четырехзначного числа?

Первый разряд может содержать 0. Есть 4 разряда, в каждом может стоять цифра от 0 до 9. Как я понимаю, это `10^4`.

Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Используйте `itertools.permutations`

Comment: @dIm0n, `len(list(permutations([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 4)))` --> `5040` ;)

Comment: @MaxU а, да, нужны не просто размещения, потому что повторы могут быть

Comment: А в первой позиции 0 разве может быть? 9*10^3 по идее надо

Comment: @dIm0n да, может

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Если не мудрить, то требуется просто вывести строковое представление чисел до 9999 с ведущими нулями:

```
for i in range(10000):
    print('{:04d}'.format(i))
```

Answer (score 8):

Для случая когда надо перебирать цифры десятичной системы, @Mbo показал самый простой и оптимальный вариант.

Если же надо перебирать другие символы, например буквы алфавита или цифры шестнадцатиричной системы, то можно воспользоваться универсальным вариантом:

```
from itertools import product

N = 4    
res = list(map("".join, product(*[list("0123456789")] * N)))
```

---

```
In [37]: len(res)
Out[37]: 10000
```

Пример с буквами:

```
In [60]: alphabet = "abc"

In [61]: N = 3

In [62]: res = list(map("".join, product(*[list(alphabet)] * N)))

In [63]: res
Out[63]:
['aaa',
 'aab',
 'aac',
 'aba',
 'abb',
 'abc',
 'aca',
 'acb',
 'acc',
 'baa',
 'bab',
 'bac',
 'bba',
 'bbb',
 'bbc',
 'bca',
 'bcb',
 'bcc',
 'caa',
 'cab',
 'cac',
 'cba',
 'cbb',
 'cbc',
 'cca',
 'ccb',
 'ccc']
```

Comment: Так лучше `res = list(map(''.join, product('0123456789', repeat=N)))`.

Answer (score 4):

```
out = []
for i in range(10):
    for k in range(10):
        for n in range(10):
            for h in range(10):
                out.append(str(i)+str(k)+str(n)+str(h))
print(out)
```

Получается список из строк, при необходимости также переводится в int.

Comment: Интересный выбор имен для переменных цикла.;-)

Comment: `O(n^4)` н-да... И кстати `i` `j` `k`

Comment: @VictorVosMottor временная сложность ровно такая же, как и во всех остальных решениях, разве что последовательная конкатенация менее эффективна чем join. и, кстати, `i`, `j`, `k` - традиционно __индексные__ переменные

Comment: @extrn А я думал у MaxU эффективней. Ну впрочем у него просто несовсем явно... `и, кстати, i, j, k - традиционно индексные переменные` -- не понял... Их обычно юзают в циклах, нет?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor `i` как переменная любого цикла - это наследие `C`, где практически любой цикл итерируется по индексам массива. Если переменная цикла содержит значение, используют соответствующие переменные: `x`, `element` и т.д. Хотя привычки трудно побороть.

Comment: @extrn `временная сложность ровно такая же` -- напрактике примерно да, ну а в теории у MBo один цикл -- стало быть `O(n)`

Comment: @VictorVosMottor у задачи, в том виде, каком она сформулирована, сложность O(1), потому, что количество цифр всегда 4, количество значений - 10, это константы. Если обобщить задачу `Есть 4 разряда, в каждом может стоять цифра от 0 до n-1`, сложность будет O(n^4), если еще обобщить `Есть m разрядов, в каждом может стоять цифра от 0 до n-1`, получится O(n^m)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor все решения в ветке, кроме решения MBo, можно обобщить на произвольное `n`, при этом решения MaxU и MBo обобщаются на произвольное `m`, т.е. самое универсальное решение у MaxU - оно легко обобщается на `n` и `m`

Answer (score 2):

Такой же `О(n^4)` как у @MrTwister, но зато в одну строчку ;)

```
print(*(int(str(i) + str(j) + str(k) + str(n)) for i in range(10) for j in range(10) for k in range(10) for n in range(10)))
```