# Как сделать перебор символов

Tags: python, linux, python-3.6, символы, перебор

Уже второй день не могу сделать алгоритм перебора для python.

У нас есть 4 символа `a b c d`

И алгоритм должен перебором вывести что-то типо этого:

```
aaaaaa
abaaaa
acaaaa
adaaaa
aabaaa
abbaaa
acbaaa
...
addddd
baaaaa
bbaaaa
...
dddddd
```

Можно как-то ето сделать. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как можно сгенерировать список всех комбинаций цифр четырехзначного числа?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1171352/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо @dIm0n за направление [на другой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1171352/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%85-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%85%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0) с такой же темой. Оттуда я нашел такой код:

```
from itertools import product

N = 4    
res = list(map("".join, product(*[list("abcd")] * N)))
```